# What far-right politicians has Hassan Iquioussen endorsed?

Tags: france, islam

[In France, Furor Over a Muslim Reality Show Star Reveals Deeper Tensions](http://www.tabletmag.com/scroll/255633/in-france-furor-over-a-muslim-reality-show-star-reveals-deeper-tensions) says that Hassan Iquioussen has endorsed far-right politicians. While I'm aware of the [horseshoe theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horseshoe_theory) in general, I assume that most far-right politicians in France not only dislike Judaism or Jews but also dislike Islam or Muslims. Who has he been endorsing?

The [French-language Wikipedia article on him](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hassan_Iquioussen) doesn't mention his endorsements.

Comment: Do you consider the last paragraph about Alain Soral to be an endorsement?

Comment: @JamesK I missed that bit.

Comment: You could write your own answer then.

Comment: "I assume that most far-right politicians in France not only dislike Judaism or Jews but also dislike Islam or Muslims" you seem to confuse politics (life?) with Star Wars. France (and in the real life too), things aren't black or white: you will find anti-muslim/jew from right to middle to left (the same is true for anti-science, and many other topics). in a partisanship political system like France you won't find precise ideas, but merely parties which carry packages of ideas from left to right.